# Overwrite user agent input stylesheet for set my css in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i try to "display:none" the input user agent box like this pic [This is my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8ynJ.png), the black box is my css style, i want only delete the "Scegli file" box.

It's possible display only my box for input?

This my html and css...

I use Qode builder and visual composer and my theme is brige.

I have the last version of all lke wp, plugin, anche theme.

Tks for all helps

Bye guys

```css
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file,  .cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:not([disabled]) {
 background-color: #282828;
 border-color: rgba(40,40,40,1);
 border-width: 1px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Lora;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: none;
}
.cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:hover,  .cf7_custom_style_1 input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:not([disabled]):hover {
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #f8b045;
 border-color: rgba(248,176,69,1);
}
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:not([disabled]):hover {
 border-color: #f8b045
}
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:not([disabled]):hover {
 background-color: #f8b045;
}
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file, input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:not([disabled]), .woocommerce-page input[type="file"] {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
 border-color: #000000;
 font-size: 16px;
/* line-height: 54px;*/
 /*height: 54px;*/
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 background-color: #000000;
 border-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: none;
}
#file_comment:hover,  .post-password-form input[type='file']:hover  input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:not([disabled]):hover  .woocommerce table.cart td.actions input[type="file"]:hover,  .woocommerce-page input[type="file"]:hover {
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #f8b045
}
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file:not([disabled]):hover,  .woocommerce table.cart td.actions input[type="file"]:hover,  .woocommerce-page input[type="file"]:hover {
 background-color: #f8b045;
}

input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-file {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
   max-width: 280px;
    /*height: 39px;*/
    /*line-height: 36px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: Raleway,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: 0;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .1s linear;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear;
    transition: all .1s linear;
    -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
    -moz-box-sizing: initial;
    box-sizing: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap uploadfile"><input type="file" name="uploadfile" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="uploadfile" accept=".pdf,.docx" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: that's means you want to hide the test of div class using css right??

Comment: I think you want to hide the default Choose File button , from the image and your description. If that is what it is then display :none has to be added like this ::input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
} and then you have style the label , span in your case.  The custom span element with a 'for' attribute attached to a hidden file input element. (The span's for attribute must match the file element's id in order for this to work).

Comment: Please search like style input file css, you will find lot of tutorials

Comment: I dont' want hide my test div, i want to hide the default choosen file box inside my black span beacuse i want to display only my span for input